# Timed loop for updating a ListBox

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to loop this specifically.

```
ListBox2.Clear
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Set wsh = Worksheets("ToolData")
m = wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To m
    If wsh.Range("E" & r) = "No" Then
        With Me.ListBox2
            .AddItem wsh.Range("B" & r)
            .Column(1, .ListCount - 1) = wsh.Range("C" & r)
            .Column(2, .ListCount - 1) = wsh.Range("F" & r)
            .Column(3, .ListCount - 1) = wsh.Range("J" & r)
            .Column(4, .ListCount - 1) = wsh.Range("K" & r)
        End With
    End If
Next r
```

I'm trying to update the list box automatically. How would I update my listBox using a timed loop? Or even real time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timed loop for UserForm\_Activate()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832005/timed-loop-for-userform-activate).  Please refrain from asking the same question multiple times.  You can edit the existing question if you need to add extra information.